# Is the static initialization order of this code implementation specific?

Tags: c#

I have a design that relies heavily on static initialization. I've noticed that after a series of OS updates, my design appears to be failing on some *older* versions of the .NET Framework (v<3.5), and only under Release configuration.

I think I've been able to narrow the issue down to a block of code similar in design to this:

```
public abstract class Foo { public static object A; }
public class Bar : Foo { 
    public static object B = InitB();
    private static object InitB(){ return A }; }

public static void Main()
{
    Foo.A = new object();
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    Console.Write((bar.B==null).ToString());
}
```

On .NET 2.0, under Release build, on my system, it appears my code is printing `true`. Whereas on .NET 4.5, it's printing `false`. Is the behavior of the code above implementation specific?

Comment: where is class A and why are you making this class so complicated?

Comment: Short answer: yes, implementation details changed with newer .NET versions. Jon Skeet has a [blog post](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx) about the differences.

Comment: @TMcKeown: why do you expect a class `A`? There is only a static property with the name `A`

Comment: ah, i see that now.  My main point of why so overly complicated for a default value stands however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code relies on `Bar`'s static constructor being called after the assignment to `Foo.A`. The language spec does not guarantee this. It only guarantees it if you actually write a static constructor, not if the compiler implicitly generates one: in that case, it may be called earlier than you expect.

To make sure your code behaves the same way in all valid implementations of .NET Framework, add a static constructor. You don't need to re-factor your initialisers, they can remain where they are.

```
public class Bar : Foo { 
    static Bar() { } // <-- add this
    public static object B = InitB();
    private static object InitB() { return A };
}
```

Alternatively, re-work your code in such a way that it still works even if the static constructor is called early.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the behaviour of the above code implementation specific

For the example above, the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758(v=vs.71).aspx) would suggest that is the case

> If a static constructor exists in the class, execution of the static field initializers occurs immediately prior to executing that static constructor. Otherwise, the static field initializers are executed at an implementation-dependent time prior to the first use of a static field of that class.

For consistency across .NET versions, and to force initialization order, you should add a static constructor to both classes.